# Optimize Switch MOSFET AC

Tags: mosfet, switches, ac

My aim is to create this using MOSFETs:

[image]

Currently, I have this schematic: (I cannot to use TRIACs because I need to cut the AC line in the middle of cycle.)

[image]

Question:
So, I'm using 4 MOSFETs for '1 switch'. Is there is a way to optimize this circuit?

If I have to do the same for the neutral, I will have to use 8 MOSFETs...

L1, and L2 are 220VAC (RMS).

Comment: "*If I have to do the same for the Neutral, I...*" is concerning. Why would you? Are these two isolated supplies? Is this safety device?

Comment: Hello @Transistor, this is not a safety device. I want to switch between two 'separate' power lines (L1,N1 <-- switch --> L2,N2), using mosfets, without using a 'mechanical' device. For this, I have to use 8 Mosfets, and I'm wondering if there is a way to reduce the number of them,

Comment: "Neutral" implies that one wire from each source has been "neutralised" by a ground connection. How do you have two neutrals? It sounds like you have two supplies which are not connected. That presents more problems if they are not properly neutralised.

Comment: Hello @Transistor, I updated my post adding a new picture as example.

Comment: Why not a relay? If you are worried about idle power consumption, there are bistable relays that only use power when switching...

Comment: This looks like a very bad idea and is probably against local regulations. A failure of your system could result in a backfeed into the other property. Fault currents could be huge. If this had to be done it would be done with mechanically interlocked contactors with properly rated circuit breakers and subject to local electrical regulations.

Comment: Hello @Transistor. I don't want to break the local regulations, it's for my home. I'm just curious.

Comment: Your diagram shows that it is for two homes and these will have independent supplies. Your circuit shows, I think, that you are more than just curious.

Comment: @Kotik_o To better elucidate the fault that Transistor mentions: You have a very good chance of damaging your MOSFETs into a failed-short condition under various scenarios, and if one of the feeds remains on (e.g. a generator) you could very easily injure (or worse) a line worker responding to an outage, or light your home on fire as fault currents flow from one grid to the other (and possibly into a hard short thereafter) through your failed system.

Comment: This has a neat self-destruct built-in. Suppose a short occurs on the output. One or more FETs fail short. The circuit breaker blows. You fix the short then restore power, but the FETs are still shorted. It looks like the switch is working fine though. Then you flip the switch, if live and neutral are the same in both houses, nothing special happens. Except, if the right FET blew, both houses' live are connected together. Now, someone decides to install a light fixture and flips the main breaker... There is no neutral, so lights are off, but there is still live in the wires from other house!

Answer (score 2):

If you have two indipendent power busses you need 4 bilateral switches.

Eeach switch needs either two MOSFETs or (highiy deprecated due much higher losses) one MOSFET and a bridge rectifier.

In both cases you also need four indipendente floating gate drivers.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9XDnr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So it all just sums up to 8 MOSFETs. This can be trimmed down only in case you reduce your specifications allowing, for instance, a single shared neutral connection which doesn't need to be switched.

In any case I hope you've taken care of switching transients, abruptly switching inductive currents would otherwise lead to pyrothecnic effects.

Also consider that 600 V BVds MOSFETs are way from enough.

Your two busses are 230 V nominal RMS voltage, this means 325 V peak  and if they happen to be out of phase by 180° each switch may see up to 650 V. Add some 150% margin and you get to the 900 V or 950 V class devices.

Edit:
I join the other members opinion in comments, you seem to overlook basic safety, regulatory and operational requirements.
I **strongly discourage** you to keep on trying. This is probably illegal but surely **very dangerous**. That's a job for professional power engineers.

Comment: Hello Carloc, Good Point! ( about to use the MOSFETS with Vds of 900V-950V). I updated my post with a new picture that represents what I'm trying to do. But, about the 8 MOSFETs, there is no way to reduce them, right?

Comment: I'm afraid that if you want a "generic" switchbox which will work whatever bus you feed you need 8 MOS. In other words, if you need a DPDT switch yes, it takes 8. If you manage do to with a SPDT switch 4 will suffice. However I join the guys above and STRONGLY  recommend not to do what you are planning, that's a challenge for professional power engineers.