# Is it possible for using a single IRF730 MOSFET to switch an AC load?

Tags: mosfet, switches

I have seen an approach here [Approach from Tamid Blog](http://tahmidmc.blogspot.com/2012/11/controlling-ac-load-with-mosfet.html) to control an AC load using MOSFET. I copied the approach in this image:

Figure 1: Modified mosfet switch
[image: Figure 1: Modified mosfet switch]

The modification is to allow the control from an Arduino the MOSFET for switching the load (at AC side with nominal current from 1-3 A) on/off. D5 is a bridge diode;

**Question:** Can you advice me on whether the schematic is correct and is there any improvement is needed? Values for resistors can be recalculated. How can I separated the ground between the high side and the MCU control side?

Thank you very much for your attention.
Please be sorry for this stupid question. I am on the learning process to electronic!

My wrong application of optocoupler is here

Figure 2: My wrong application of Optocoupler
[image: Figure 2: Wrong application of Optocoupler]

Question 2: Can it work with this. I doubt the MOSFET will die as the Vgs is too high (exceed the +- 30 V in the datasheet). I saw an option here [High voltage mosfet switch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wakrtG4XesE&t=296s)

Figure 3: Optocoupler with MOSFET from youtube video
[image: Figure 3: Optocoupler]

Figure 4: Here is the capture from youtube!
[image: Figure 4: Youtube video schematic]
and here Figure 5.
[image: Figure 5: Youtube video schematic from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3H7y3JhOAk]

Comment: (1) What's going to provide power for the gate driver circuit when Q1 is on? There will be no voltage available for D3, U4, etc. (2) What's D2 for? There are already 2S2P (two-series, two-parallel) diodes in D5 and another single diode in Q1.

Comment: I see your point. Can I use a 5V control signal directly at the gate without the use of the optocoupler? If it is the case, GND is not isolated at the high voltage side and the MCU side. Please advice!

Comment: Are you permitted to have multiple diodes in the solution?

Comment: Hi Math, as @Transistor questioned, I released that there is no power for the gate when the Mosfet conducted so I revised the image to the original approach. My question is changed from how to make the control MCU be safe from this approach as it seem that the GND is not isolated.

Comment: You may use photovoltaic optocoupler. It gives isolation without second DC source.

Comment: Can you advice me one approach as the original post has PC817 but I made it wrongly!
This is my original sketch
https://easyeda.com/editor#id=f5e7d3bbf8e242ddbb1d4e9e2459576b

Comment: Tip: if you want to "ping" someone and send a message to their inbox you need to use the syntax `@uesrname` with no spaces (even if there are spaces in the user's name). You can only ping one user per comment.

Comment: I @Transistor, thank you for your advice, I revised the original question and I also see a similar approach on the youtube (mentioned in the main question). Can you advice me a bit on this.

Comment: @Transistor, Thank you for your answer. Your writing bright me a lot on optocoupler (such as TP817, MOC30xx) and this Photovoltaic.

Comment: As aside note I don't find any good reason for using a single MOS+bridge. Much better two MOSs with joined sources. Control circuit is the same, board space for the extra MOS is the same or less than the bridge, forward drop and hence wasted power typically less. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/529073/optimize-switch-mosfet-ac/529090#529090

Comment: Thanks @carloc, I am the way to look for an universal AC switch (work with inductive/ resitive/ capacitive load of 1-5 A, 220VAC) that is better than Triac and I found that both Bridge + MOS and 2 MOS are ok to replace. The only issues that I am struggling with is the isolation of gate driver to the MCU. The photovoltaic output option as mentioned by Transistor is a good replacement  for complicated gate driver but it hard to find the part in Vietnam. Can you recommend me a good gate driver for 2MOS with thanks!

Comment: VOM1271 from Vishay. You can find it on Ali.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Photovoltaic Output Optocoupler would solve a lot of problems for you. Here's one I picked at random.

[image]

*Figure 1. The [TOSHIBA TLP591B](https://docs.rs-online.com/f367/0900766b808496c0.pdf) consists of an aluminum galium arsenide
infrared emitting diode optically coupled to a series connected
photo−diode array in a six lead plastic DIP package.*

[image]

*Figure 2. The **open-circuit** output voltage plotted against the LED I<sub>F</sub>.*

Since this generates power for driving the MOSFET gate it means you don't need to worry about a PSU for gate control. Things you do need to watch out for are:

- Switching time. You want your MOSFET to switch quickly so that it spends minimum time dissipating power while going from off to on and back again.
- Drive voltage: is it enough for your MOSFET. (I didn't check.)